# webpage disappears whenever I type anything in the input

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I've been trying simple programs to understand React better. Here's the code I've written.

```
const Previewer = (props) => {
  let {text} = props
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  let [text, setText] = useState()
  return (
    <>
      <label for="text-edit">Editor</label>
      <textArea id="text-edit" value={text} placeholder="Type Here..." onChange={(event) =>
          setText({
            text: event.target.value
          })}
      ></textArea>
      {console.log(text)}
      <Previewer text={text} /> 
    </>
  )
}

const root = document.querySelector('#root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />,  root)
```

The problem I'm having is that whenever I start typing anything into the textarea element, the entire webpage disappears. I'm assuming this is because of component lifecycle issue but I'm not certain. Could anyone explain me where I'm going wrong with this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in is App component ,onChange you need to pass a string value not an object , and it is `<textarea>` not `<textArea>`

```
const App = () => {
  let [text, setText] = useState()
  return (
    <>
      <label for="text-edit">Editor</label>
      <textarea id="text-edit" value={text} placeholder="Type Here..." onChange={(event) =>
          setText(event.target.value)}
      ></textarea>
      {console.log(text)}
      <Previewer text={text} /> 
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working now finally. Found that I was getting confused between `setState()` and `setText()`. I used `setText()`  the way you'd use `setState()` forgetting that text was a string and not an object. Also I corrected the `<textarea>` tag.

Comment: Cool , you can upvote the answer and accept it ,if you find it useful, it will help others who face the same issue